# How to use dark theme for section of the screen

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a material UI & reactjs app and decided to use a bright content area (with black text on white bg) and a dark menu (white text on black bg).

I know that material UI supports both out of the box ('light' and 'dark') theme settings, but I could not figure out how to use those just for a certain section of the screen (just the menu).

Could you help me with this?

(Of cause I know that I could style everything with CSS, but I wonder if there is an easier way to do this.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have any number of `MuiThemeProvider` elements that you need within your element hierarchy. So you can have a structure like the following:

```
const mainTheme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    type: "light"
  }
});

const darkTheme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    type: "dark"
  }
});

function App(props) {
  return (
    <MuiThemeProvider theme={mainTheme}>

        <MuiThemeProvider theme={darkTheme}>
          <YourMenu/>
        </MuiThemeProvider>
        <YourContent/>
    </MuiThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

Here's a working example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/61z38zjr7w

The example is a modified version of the permanent drawer demo:

https://material-ui.com/demos/drawers/#permanent-drawer

Answer (score 2):

### For Material UI v5

[This accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55344029/11067496) uses Material **v4**. If you're using Material UI **v5**, the `createMuiTheme` and `MuiThemeProvider` has been [deprecated in v5](https://mui.com/material-ui/migration/v5-style-changes/#theme-structure) in favor of and [`createTheme`](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theming/#createtheme-options-args-theme) and  [`ThemeProvider`](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theming/#themeprovider) respectively. So,

```
const mainTheme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    type: "light"
  }
});

const darkTheme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    type: "dark"
  }
});

function App(props) {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={mainTheme}>
        <ThemeProvider theme={darkTheme}>
          <YourMenu/>
        </ThemeProvider>
        <YourContent/>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

Here's a working example, which is modified from the [permanent drawer demo](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-drawer/#permanent-drawer):

[image: Edit MUI Partial Dark Theme]