# How do I change the text color for certain sections using a custom Theme palette and without overriding another Theme?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

These issues were my starting points:

[How do I set custom fonts for header, body, and button tags for Material UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55367081/how-do-i-set-custom-fonts-for-header-body-and-button-tags-for-material-ui/55367542#55367542) 
[How to use dark theme for section of the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55342848/how-to-use-dark-theme-for-section-of-the-screen/55344029#55344029)

```
import { createMuiTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import grey from "@material-ui/core/colors/grey";


const mainTheme = createMuiTheme({
  typography: {
    h2: {
      fontFamily: "campton-light"
    },
    h3: {
      fontFamily: "campton-book"
    },
    body1: {
      fontFamily: "campton-book"
    }
  }
});

const darkTheme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    type: "dark"
  }
});

export { mainTheme, darkTheme };
```

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { withStyles, MuiThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import {mainTheme, darkTheme} from "../Theme";

const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1
  }
});

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider theme={mainTheme}>
       <Typography variant="h2">Some text here as h2 "campton-light"</Typography>
        <MuiThemeProvider theme={darkTheme}>
          <Typography variant="body1">Some text here should be dark theme with the "body1" font family but shows as default "Roboto" font with type: "dark" text color.</Typography>
        </MuiThemeProvider>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}

Apps.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default withStyles(styles)(Apps);
```

Here's a working sample: https://codesandbox.io/s/8nm56kzlj2

I forked over another user's sample just to show my little sample. You will see my insert.

Comment: It opens fine for me on Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: [Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/20m8398j70). Is this u want?

Comment: @Ram_UI I don't think that method will work for me. The same header tags are used throughout the design and I can't have colors assigned specifically for the those tags. Basically we have dark cards and white cards and the text color has to be in contrast with the background. So the header tags should only have the fontFamily types assigned and the text color will need to change for the entire card component hence my reasoning for using a theme palette to address this.

Comment: I ended up using using the spread operator for each of the header tags in darkTheme to extend the first theme and then added the type: "dark". The first theme that is set in the component seems to not allow any additional font color changes.